# Separating GET and POST controller actions cleanly for form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a page that has a lot of data populated in the controller, and a form.

My question is actually quite simple: must I repeat all of this population code in the POST version of the action or is there some simplification to only handle the data posted?

The form itself is a partial view with the rest of the page data unchanging on post.

edit: I've looked at the `get-post-redirect` but I don't think this helps with code duplication.

Comment: Repeat what _population code_? Are you referring to `SelectLists`? Show some code so we can understand what your doing

Comment: That completely depends on your logic and whether you actually need the values that are defined for your model but are not included in the form. If you do need them, then obviously you populate the model in the controller's POST before processing. There is no code duplication because you'd then have a method to populate a model which you'd call from both GET and POST. Or stuff all data into the page using hidden fields, if that is not a security concern.

Comment: You can create a helper function that executes the code, that would be duplicated otherwise. Then just call that function in the GET and POST action

Comment: @GSerg gotcha, it's actually an identical page, with form validation errors or success messages. So I'll just put all that page populating code into a function.

Answer (score 0):

The prescribed method for doing this is to use a ViewModel that contains the logic for populating the model. a "LoadData()" (or somesuch) method on the ViewModel would be called from both controller actions.

Comment: A view model should not contain logic for populating its properties, especially not calling a service. A view model contains only those properties necessary for display/editing in a view.

Comment: Lots of writing on the matter seems to disagree. For instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx.

Comment: I doubt that, and what the point of giving me a link to an article on the MVVM pattern when this is MVC